# Spring Boot Rest and JPA Deserializing Nested Entities with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jpa, spring-boot, jackson

I am new to Spring Boot, Jackson, and JPA. I am attempting to build an RESTful application. From my understanding of the Spring Boot documentation, much of the work of deserializing data and returning JSON is "magically" handled by the Spring framework (when the appropriate starter/dependencies included).

My Controller endpoint is simple.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.midamcorp.roominspections.models.*;
import com.midamcorp.roominspections.service.ItemService;

 @RestController
@RequestMapping("/item")
public class ItemController {
    @Autowired
    private ItemService itemService;

@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Item> getItems() {
    return itemService.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/{id}")
public Item getItem(@PathVariable int id) {
    return itemService.findOne(id);
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="/page/{pageNumber}")
public List<Item> getItemsByPage(@PathVariable int pageNumber) {
    return itemService.findByPage(pageNumber);
}
}
```

However, my classes (JPA entities) exhibit some relationships. In example:

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;

       @Entity
@Table(name="Items")
public class Item {

    public Item() {}
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int ItemID;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="CommentCategoryID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private CommentCategory commentCategory;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="ItemCategoryID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private ItemCategory itemCategory; 

@OneToMany(mappedBy="item",targetEntity=ReportDetail.class)
private Set<ReportDetail> detail;

private String ItemName;
private String ItemDescription;
private String ItemType;
@Column(name="PageNumber")
private int pageNumber;
private int PossPoints;
private int CommentCategoryID;
private int ItemCategoryID;

// getters and setters follow
}
```

Whenever, I attempt to access the item endpoint, I receive the following error:

```
 Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not deserialize; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not deserialize (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.midamcorp.roominspections.models.Item["commentCategory"]->com.midamcorp.roominspections.models.CommentCategory["comments"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->com.midamcorp.roominspections.models.Comment["reportDetails"])
```

Now I understand the issue lies in deserializing the data (through Jackson), and the problem "ends" with the reportDetails property of the Comment entity. However, I have inspected both the Comment and ReportDetails entities and could find nothing amiss.

Comment

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Comments")
public class Comment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int CommentID;

public Comment() {}

@OneToMany(mappedBy="comment", targetEntity=ReportDetail.class)
private Set<ReportDetail> reportDetails;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="CommentCategoryID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private CommentCategory commentCategory;

private int CommentCategoryID;
private String CommentBody;

// getters and setters
}
```

ReportDetail

```
import javax.persistence.*;

    @Entity
@Table(name="ReportDetailRows")

public class ReportDetail {

    public ReportDetail() {}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int ReportRowID;
private int ReportID;
private int ItemID;
private int CommentID;
private int PointsDeducted;
private String ItemIMG;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="CommentID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Comment comment;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="ReportID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private ReportSummary summary;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="ItemID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Item item;

// getters and setters
}
```

Repository interfaces (extending the CrudRepository) and a Service layer are used.

The following is an example service:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.midamcorp.roominspections.models.Item;
import com.midamcorp.roominspections.models.ItemRepo;

   @Service
    @Transactional
    public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {
    @Autowired
    private ItemRepo itemRepo;

    @Override
    public List<Item> findAll() {
    return (List<Item>) itemRepo.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Item> findByPage(int pageNumber) {
    return itemRepo.findByPageNumber(pageNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public Item findOne(int id) {
    return itemRepo.findOne(id);
    }

}
```

In my experience with .NET, I would have to create DTOs (using a library such as AutoMapper) to flatten the entities for transfer. However, from my review of the Jackson documentation, it seemed as if the library handles such flattening automatically (note, I realize it is not a good practice to transfer such large volumes of data; as I am new to the technologies, I simply want to get it working first) . If DTOs are required, where would they be situated? For example, in the Controller, Service, Repository, etc?

I truly appreciate any advice. I have searched around but have been unable to find a solution for my particular problem.

Comment: My first guess that there is a problem with wrong collection type used:
org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet. Try to use some collection from java not hibernate.

Comment: we need to see your imports aswell.

Comment: @Pulkownik Thanks for the advice. If you are referring the Entity classes, they all appear to be using java.util.Set<>. Is this correct?

Comment: @KellyMarchewa Yes that's correct, but somewhere in code you are using the Set implementation as org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet, find it and change to HashSet for example.

Comment: @JalalSordo the post has been edited to add imports.

Comment: @Pulkownik That is very interesting. I see where you are getting that (in the error message), but, after setting some breakpoints, best I can tell, Spring Boot/Hibernate is converting the Comments Set to a Persistent Set behind the scenes (perhaps due to the annotations?). Perhaps someone more knowledgeable about the framework would be able to explain. Thanks.

Comment: try to load eagerly all the relationships or replace the Set with Collection or List  on the Comment Class reportDetails.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and advice. Eventually, I just decided to do the "right" thing and create DTOs (used at the Controller level). This resolved the noted issue. I wish I knew why the error was encountered (I know the direct use of Entity classes is not good practice, but I thought it should have at least worked for testing), but it is still a mystery to me.

Comment: The error was likely due to the `@OneToMany private Set<ReportDetail> detail` field. After the controller method was executed, the entity became detached. When Jackson proceeded to serialize the entity, it tried to serialize the `Comment.detail`, and a `LazyInitializationException` followed (you would likely have seen it deeper in the stack trace). You should have used either `@JsonIgnore` or `@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)`.